# R - Split data frame by first space only

Tags: r

I've got this form of information saved in variable 'fechas'

```
"09/03/2013 10:59:21 PM" 
"09/03/2013 10:58:19 PM" 
"09/03/2013 10:57:06 PM"
"09/03/2013 10:55:31 PM" 
"09/03/2013 10:52:34 PM" 
"09/03/2013 10:51:10 PM"
"09/03/2013 10:45:06 PM" 
"09/03/2013 10:18:53 PM" 
"09/03/2013 10:10:47 PM"
"09/03/2013 10:00:28 PM" 
"09/03/2013 09:57:42 PM" 
"09/03/2013 09:32:32 PM"
```

I'm able to separate the date, but I'm unable to just get the time with the AM or  PM corresponding.

I've tried this.

```
horas <- strsplit(fechas,"2013 ")
```

But they are also 2014 and 2015 years assigned. 
How could I obtain only the hour with its respective AM/PM analog time?

Comment: Are the character strings all the same length?

Comment: yes they have the same length @polka - the entire result, would be something like "10:59:21 PM"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to date/time and then `format` back as required:

```
format(as.POSIXct(x, format="%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"), "%I:%M:%S %p")
# [1] "10:59:21 PM" "10:58:19 PM" "10:57:06 PM" "10:55:31 PM" "10:52:34 PM" "10:51:10 PM"
# [7] "10:45:06 PM" "10:18:53 PM" "10:10:47 PM" "10:00:28 PM" "09:57:42 PM" "09:32:32 PM"
```

Or use `?regex` to extract the part you need:

```
sub("^.+ (\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} (A|P)M)", "\\1", x)
#or:
sub(".+/\\d{4} (.+)", "\\1", x)
```

Or use regex to remove the part you don't need:

```
sub(".+/\\d{4} ", "", x)
```

Or split on `/YYYY` representing the four year numbers:

```
strsplit(x, "(?<=/\\d{4}) ", perl=TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "09/03/2013"  "10:59:21 PM"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "09/03/2013"  "10:58:19 PM"
# ...
```

Or as @Henrik notes, for this simple case, you can just use `substring` to grab everything from the 12th character onwards:

```
substring(x,12)
```

Comment: Or because the length is fixed: `substring(x, 12)`

Comment: This is better practice.

Comment: @polka - "better" is a bit subjective. It's straight forward for this case, but being able to `format` a date can be very handy if for instance you want to switch from 12 hour to 24 hour time, or to extract day + month abbreviation etc. `as.POSIXct` will also gracefully deal with situations like `x2 <- c("9/3/2013 10:59", "09/03/2013 10:59")`

Answer (score 2):

Then just subset the string.

```
substr(c, 12,22)
```

Or if you need to return a list of values.

```
newList<-sapply(ListOfTimes, substr, 12,22)
```